# PHP Disposition-Notification-To

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to get a read receipt from my PHP emails, here's my code:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ABC <do-not-reply@abc.com> \n";
$headers .= "Disposition-Notification-To: abc@hotmail.com \n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
```

I tried opening the email on my phone and outlook. In both cases, received no email to confirm that the email was open.

I also tried

```
$headers .= "Read-Receipt-To: abc@hotmail.com \n";
```

And

```
$headers .= "X-Confirm-Reading-To: abc@hotmail.com \n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Read receipts are entirely up to the receiver, there is no way to guarantee one, and many webmail clients will explicitly ignore this for privacy reasons.

Try using Outlook (the office suite application, not the webmail/hotmail clone, not sure which you used) and seeing if you get a popup that says "do you want to send a read receipt? yes / no"